# Rails tests are using server in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I just set up Puma and it's working fine as a development server.

**When I run an integration test, Puma is starting in development mode, not test mode.**

Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem puma
end
```

test/test_helper.rb

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  require 'rack/handler/puma'
  Capybara.server = :puma
  Capybara.register_server("puma") do |app, port|
    server = Puma::Server.new(app)
    server.add_tcp_listener(Capybara.server_host, port)
    server.run
  end
end
```

A test:

```
✗ RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/computers_test.rb -n /polt/
Started with run options -n /polt/ --seed 3050
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:49875
Use Ctrl-C to stop
...
```

Comment: What worked for you sscirrus?

Comment: @ZedTuX Unfortunately I can't remember. I don't think it was one of the answers below, but this was also a situation from 2.5 years ago.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same behavior happen when you run `rake test` ?

I'd make sure in your `config/puma.rb` file (create one if you don't have one ) you have a line like `environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }` - without it I was seeing the same behavior you were.

Comment: This isn't working for me in rails 5.1 system tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `RACK_ENV` as the `RAILS_ENV` to :

```
RACK_ENV="test" RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/computers_test.rb -n /polt/
```

Then the puma server will use the test environment:

```
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:49875
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"
```

in your test file, before all tests.

This is actually similar to @ZedTuX answer, but I cannot comment there.